# How to convert RDD string(xml format) to dataframe in spark java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, distributed-computing, databricks

Good solution available in below link if xml data available in file,
https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

Below code convert xml to DataSet by loading physical file..

```
Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
                                   .option("rowTag", "book")
                                   .load("file:///C:/books.xml");
```

> But If xml data available in JavaRdd then how to convert into
>   Dataset?